# URL parent category slug displays twice

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, category, url-rewrite

The url slugs when refining by category on the store, the url displays the parent category twice.

> site.com/x/x/y

In the configuration>web:

```
 web rewrites: on unsecured 
 base url: http://guytgunter.com/shop/
 default web url : catalog/category/view/id/3
```

Which the catalog would be the shop slug, category would be a variable category and so on.

How do i change my url structure to instead display

> site.com/x/y

Comment: You have a category "Shop" with your subcategories included, right?

Comment: @StefanGregori that is correct. shop is main category

Comment: well, then its not doubling. one "shop" comes from url one "shop" from you category. is it possible for you to remove "shop" category and move you subcategories one level up?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments it appears you have your shop under the url structure `/shop` so that all pages contain that part of the url. You then seem to on top of  that have a category that itself has the url `shop`

This means that this category has the url `/shop/shop` where the first is part of the base url and the second is part of the category.

You could consider choosing a different section for the base url or for the category.

Or if the category is the root category then simply removing it completely.